# How to tie cell choice from dropdown list to content of other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

On a given range of cells, I have imposed the following data validation. The options come from a list contained in another sheet (`Legends`):

[image]

For each of these cells, I would like the option `H` to be selected whenever the corresponding cell in another sheet is non-empty. So I have tried:

**in Sowing 20!O4**`=IF(Harvest 20!O4<>0,Legends!A10,"")`

which gives error. Also the following does not work:

**in Sowing 20 O4**`=IF(Harvest 20!O4<>0,"H","")`

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error you are running into the space in the name of the sheet.  Have you tried:

```
=IF('Harvest 20'!O4<>0,Legends!A10,"")
```

The space in the sheet's name is most likely the issue.